# Spring batch Lock when Reader and Writer works with the same table

Tags: spring-batch, bitronix

We are evaluating spring batch (version 3.0.3), and for it we have made a simple data process

**Our test:**

We have 500k rows in a table, and we want to process it updating a field as a flag of "row processed"

Our job definition is like this:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd"
    profile="job1">

    <job id="job1">
        <step id="step1">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="itemReader"  writer="itemWriter"
                    commit-interval="#{jobParameters['commit.interval']?:'100'}" />     
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>
```

We are using a JdbcCursorItemReader as reader (query like SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE field3 = '2Process') and a JdbcBatchItemWriter as writer (UPDATE table SET field3 = 'Processed' WHERE field1 = :field1 and field2 = :field2)

Our database is a DB2/zOS configured with a lock by page in the table we are using

We use Bitronix as Transaction Manager

When we launch it, we are obtaing this Exception:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: Error for batch element #8: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-913, SQLSTATE=57033, SQLERRMC=00C9008E;00000302;DBABCD  .TSTABLE .X'000201', DRIVER=4.19.26
```

It seems that the exception occurs because the Tx of the reader is not the same that the Tx for the writer for the database. And we are having a block in page 201 for it.

Obviously, if we change the isolation level of the select, adding with ur, the batch is finishing ok.

Our question is, this database lock, could be a problem caused for transaction manager because bitronix doesn't support nested trasactions? Or it seems to be a problem with db2 database and the locking policy defined

Also, we don't know if is a good practice having a spring batch with a step that reads and writes to the same table

Edit: Sorry, you are right, big mistake in my explanation, **db2/zOS**

Comment: Just wondering, how do you configure DB2/400 to lock by page? To the best of my knowledge, there are only object locks, and record locks. No page locks available.

Comment: Something doesn't sound right here.  Are you configuring your `JdbcCursorItemReader` to setUseSharedExtendedConnection?  If not, it's connection shouldn't participate in transactions (it should be a separate connection).

Comment: If we set to true setUseSharedExtendedConnection, we get this Exception `ResultSet holdability HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT not permitted in a XA connection. ERRORCODE=-4476, SQLSTATE=null` We have also to set property downgradeHoldCursorsUnderXA to true?

Answer (score 2):

Hello first since you have a page locking and not a row locking when having an update intensivle operation such as a batch. Having deadlocks is inevitable. So you have to just accept it. What you need to do is to create architecture that can tolerate it in a good way.

First I would strongly recomend you to switch from Page locking to Row locking. The very idea of Page locking is to enable the database for extremly read intensive applications. I seriously doubt your application is such which means that the small overhead the row locking would present is negligable trade off for the conviniese it would present.

But lets presume you don't switch the page locking what are your alternativesin order to reduce to minimum the deadlocks:

1. Reduce the size of the page!
2. Shuffle the records. For example don't make the batch process sequentialy the IDS if you use 10 threads make the first thread to select every 10th record snd thread to select every 9th record. Even best sort it by some random factor when you select the readers.
3. Use batching but do not batch multiple records. You can decrease the chunk size as much as possible. This way you will decrease the overal locking factor.

Basicly whatever you do you need to think in the direction how can I ensure that I have as short transactions as possible and hit as many different pages as possible.

But even then you can not guarantee that at least one deadlock is not hit. Which means you need to implement RETRY logic. That is mandatory.

And as a conclusion, just save yourself all this hussle and configure DB2 for row locking.

Probably if it was me I would have set th chunk size to 1-2-3 something like that, but definatly not 100.

Comment: DB2/400 only does row locking.

Comment: I can not comment with 100% certainty but I seriously doubt it. I configured it for z/OS on one Z11 (was it Z11? don|t remember) mainframe 3 years ago. I think you should doublecheck this.

Comment: I can find no way on the IBM i platform to do page locks in SQL or with native file access. Locks only exist at the row and object level. I don't know about Z/OS.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy  well the guy has explicitly specified page locks in his question. So I am giving him answer for page locks :) I don't have experience with AS400 myself.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy but I also did a search for AS400 and did not found it like you. So I am also interested  in the answer :)

Comment: You were right, sorry I was confused with another one. The affected table was in a zOS, I have edited my post

Comment: @Kubero great ;)now put +1 vote for telling you What your operating system is :)

Comment: @Kubero one question. Is your batch paralelized, or are you running in single thread? My post is buildt on presumption that your batch is paralelized.

Comment: @Kubero Ok my bad, have you tryed SELECT for READ ONLY clause?

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov Yes, I tried and the result was the same. I only change the page locked, modifying fetchSize value or commit interval value

Comment: @Kubero is your update statement in the writer aways hiting a single row?

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov Yes

Comment: @Kubero I think you should try a run without Bitronix just to rule it out. My presumtion is that if you run with Bitronix you are using XA transaction. Meanwhile i will think What Else may cause this.

Comment: @Kubero also check the default isolation level of DB2 on zos. I have some memory that by default it was not CS.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov We have tried without Bitronix with the same result. At the moment, the only way we have found for avoid blocks is using SingleConnectionDataSource.